# Apache mod_rewrite redirects to http with 302 instead of https

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

In apache 2.2 I am using mod_rewrite and I have a rewrite rule as -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?mysite/?
RewriteRule (.*)mysite/(.*) $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

This rewrites this url -

```
https://www.domain.com/mysite/about/
```

to

```
https://www.domain.com/about/
```

The rule seems to work. But when I see the network trace in chrome developer tools or httpwatch I can see redirects with http protocol with 302. The trace is below (I have removed the timings from trace and copied only the redirects)

```
GET 301 Redirect to http://www.domain.com/about     https://www.domain.com/mysite/about
GET 302 Redirect to https://www.domain.com/about    http://www.domain.com/about
GET 302 Redirect to http://www.domain.com/about/    https://www.domain.com/about
GET 302 Redirect to https://www.domain.com/about/   http://www.domain.com/about/
GET 200 html    https://www.domain.com/about/
```

I would like to avoid the 302 redirects to http://...... and just have a 301 redirect as per my rewrite rule. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first redirect (the one you talk about) works as expected and sends the user to the new page with a 301. However, it looks like the system you are using forces a '/' at the end of the URI and does another redirect because of that.

Maybe something like this would work better:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?mysite/?
RewriteRule (.*)mysite/(.*)/? https://www.example.com/$1$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Yet your trace shows 4 redirects... I'm not too sure I understand why there is an extra 2 redirects in there.

Comment: Thanks, tweaking the rule and also combining few conditions I was able  to resolve the additional redirects. But to solve the changing protocol problem I had to forcefully redirect to https.


RewriteRule (.*)mysite/(.*)/? https://$1$2/ [R=301,L]

Comment: Ah! Yes! Sorry for the missing protocol. I'm glad you succeeded.